# I continue to get garbage values in an array that have been modified from another array, in a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm a bit new to programming so the answer to my problem has not become obvious, although I have tried to accomplish the task a number of ways.

The issue is that I'm trying to take an array of words, remove any punctuation from the array, and place the new words into a separate array.  I attempted to do this but I keep getting garbage values when I output the new array.

The code reads:

```
norm(sepwords1,sepwords2,numwords);      <- where I called it in main

void norm(string words[], string wordz[],int count)       
{

        int i;
        int x;
       
        string newstring="";
        char current;
       
         
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
        for(x=0; x<words[i].length();x++)
        {        
          current= words[i].at(x);
                if(ispunct(current)==0)
                {
                newstring += current;
                }
        
        }        
                wordz[i]= newstring;
        }
 
}
```

the full main function is:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{



int count = argc;
int i;
string filename[count];
ifstream infile;
string fromfile[1000];
int numdata;
int pass;
char current;
int sum;
string masterstring="";
int x;
string sepwords[2000];
int sum1;
string temp="";
int start;
int fin;
string newstring="";
string newfile[1000];
int place;
int numwords;
string sepwords1[2000];
string newmaster="";
int j=0;
string currentz;
string highmark;
int index[2000];
string sepwords2[2000];
int counta=0;

for(i=0; i < count-1; i++) 
{
filename[i] = argv[i+1];
}

for( i=0; i < count-1; i++)
    {
    infile.open(filename[i].c_str());
    
    numdata=0;  
    
    while(!infile.eof())
    {
    
    getline(infile, fromfile[numdata], '\n');
    numdata++;
    
    }


    
    

    for(i=0; i<numdata; i++)
    {
    cout<<fromfile[i]<<endl;
    masterstring += fromfile[i] + " ";                                      //NUMBER ONE
    }

    

    numwords = split(masterstring, sepwords);
    cout<<numwords<<endl;                                                       //NUMBER TWO


    }

    for(i=0;i<numwords;i++)
    {
        newstring = toupper(sepwords[i].at(0));         
        newstring += sepwords[i].substr(1);
        sepwords1[i] = newstring;
        newstring="";
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<numwords;i++)
    {
    
    
    newmaster += sepwords1[i] + " ";
       j++;
          if(j > 10)
          {
           newmaster+= '\n';
           j=0;
          }

    }
    cout<<newmaster<<endl;                                              //NUMBER THREE



    norm(sepwords1,sepwords2,numwords);
    
        for(i=0;i<numwords;i++)
    {
    cout<<sepwords2<<endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you declare your original arrays that you pass into `norm`? Is there any reason you are using arrays and not `std::vector`, as I assume this list of strings could be variable?

Comment: I think you want to newstring="" for every iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: I did not use a vector simply because I haven't gotten as far as to know how to implement one :P

Comment: @Sam, `<vector>` is part of the C++ standard library. If this is homework, then I can understand that... And can you post the full `main` function as well?

Comment: This line is wrong "cout<<sepwords2<<endl;" You are outputting the pointer to the whole array.  You want something like "cout<<sepwords2[i]<<endl;"

Comment: @Sam, not to worry, I've done much worse :).  Oh and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by gargage output?

If I call your function with this (g++ 4.4.5)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int
main  (int ac, char **av)
{
  int numwords = 3;
  string sepwords1[] = {"one,", "two", "three"};
  string sepwords2[numwords];
  norm(sepwords1,sepwords2,numwords);  
  for(size_t i=0;i<numwords;++i){
    std::cout<<"sepwords2["<<i<<"] = "<<sepwords2[i]<<std::endl;
  }

}
```

then I get the output

```
sepwords2[0] = one
sepwords2[1] = onetwo
sepwords2[2] = onetwothree
```

Is this not what you want?

If you don't want concatination, then you need to reset the newword variable,

```
  wordz[i]= newstring;  //this is in your norm function 
  newstring="";         //this is the line I added.
```

then the output is

```
sepwords2[0] = one
sepwords2[1] = two
sepwords2[2] = three
```

Comment: Somewhat like that.  I just have to remove punctuation from each word (if it has punctuation) and store it in the secondary array.  Using the code I provided, when I cout from sepwords2[], i get "0xffbf5828" for every element.  Am I missing something? Also, i dont understand what you did to remove the comma

Comment: @sam The comer is removed because you have the "if(ispunct(current)==0)" check before you concatenate to the string - I didn't alter your function at all except the added line that I indicated.

Comment: Oh right, yes I knew what the ispunct function did, I thought you might have done it a different way.  But I did add your suggestion and I see why it makes sense, but I keep getting the value 0xffbf5828.  Could it be something elsewhere in the code? Everything worked up until that point and I declared them in main as : "sepwords1[2000]" and "sepwords2[2000]"

Comment: @Sam - try to have the code working all inside `main`, using code from Tom or myself.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should work, but there's probably a problem in the main function, such as with your arrays and the fact that you have to use two, so one reason I see for this behavior could be your array sizes don't match each other, and the one storing the original strings is larger than the one you're copying to.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   const int SIZE = 5;
   string oldArray[SIZE] = {"He,llo", "Wor,ld", "H,ow", "Ar,e.", "Y,O,U"};
   string newArray[SIZE];

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      // Moved this into the loop for ease, otherwise your
      // original code would have kept appending to this
      // newString variable unless you cleared it later
      std::string newString = "";
      for (int x = 0; x < oldArray[i].length(); ++x) {
            char current = oldArray[i].at(x);
            if (ispunct(current) == 0)
            {
               newString += current;
            }
      }
      newArray[i] = newString;
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      std::cout << newArray[i] << '\n';
   }
}
```

That's mostly your code, with a few tweaks to fix the concatenation problem of keeping `newString` around but without clearing it later.

You can do this problem more succinctly by using the std `<algorithm>` stuff, and by using `<vector>` which will handle growth and resizing for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> stringsToCopy;
    stringsToCopy.push_back("Hel,lo,");
    stringsToCopy.push_back("th,ere.");

    // Make a copy of the other vector, since it seems like you want to keep
    // the original data. This will copy all the elements from the stringsToCopy
    // vector.
    std::vector<std::string> newStrings = stringsToCopy;

    // simplicity, but you could use an iterator as well, which would be
    // more verbose
    for (int i = 0; i < newStrings.size(); ++i) {
        // get a reference to the current string in the
        // vector for convenience, so we can use a shorter
        // name for it
        std::string& s = newStrings[i];

        // because remove_if doesn't actually delete things from a 
        // container, we should also call the string's erase method
        s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), ispunct), s.end());
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < newStrings.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << newStrings[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will try to learn how to use vectors more proficiently as I do not really have a clue at the moment.  I thought I'd add though, that both arrays were declared in main with a size of 2000, so I'm not sure if that's the exact error. (or maybe I misinterpreted what you were saying.)

Comment: @Sam - 2000 elements is fine - what's the `count` you pass into `norm`? Is it 2000 or the actual number of strings that `words` contains?

Comment: I posted the full main function, count should be the number of element in the original array.   Oh I forgot to add that there's another function in use to determine the numbers of words in the array, but that has been working so far so I doubt it is the issue

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are fixed size arrays. If you need to add and remove elements from an "array" you should use a list or vector, which are sequences of variable size.